# Errors running builder 'Jboss Knowledge Base Builder' on project 'XXXXX'. Unknown tag! pos = 3 poolCount = 12

Tags: java, deployment, build, apache-camel, jboss7.x

After an upgrade of Apache Camel version (from 2.20.0 to 2.24.2), the Maven update project and compilation still work, but not the Project > Build on Eclipse. Therefore, my project can no longer be deployed.

Here is the error on the build :

```
Errors running builder 'Jboss Knowledge Base Builder' on project 'XXXXX'. Unknown tag! pos = 3 poolCount = 12
```

Errors on deployment :

```
WFLYSRV0003 : impossible to index the module-info.class on C:/work/apps/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/deployments/XXXXXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/asm-7.1.jar : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount=12
```

and

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.createMininumEscapeHandler(Ljava/lang/Class;)
```

I tried some stuffs but it still didn't work :

- restart Eclipse
- go to Porperties > Builders > disable JBoss Knowledge Base Builder, the build worked but deployment KO
- enable JBoss Knowledge Base Builder again. Build KO again.

Do you guys have any idea about this problem ? Any suggestions are welcome.